# Block access to page using JavaScript / other method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip-address, tumblr, privacy

### Some Background

I have a tumblog.

I also have an *insane* ex-girlfriend.

Said individual has been accessing my posts obsessively and I find this to be rather unnerving given the nature of our relationship (or lack thereof). My goal is to prevent access to her, or anyone who could be her / her friends / family without having to change my established URL.

### Plan of Attack

Since I do not host my blog on a 3rd party host, I have little access to tools that would aid in blocking her access. However, I do own hosting if there is a solution that requires it. I'm no expert and as far as I can tell JavaScript is the only way to, at very least, trick her into believing she cannot access my page.

I've hacked together a script and would ***really*** appreciate some guidance. Using jQuery and the jQuery Cookie plug-in, I've come up with some code that demonstrates my goal. ***Let's get to it.***

```
var ips = "{text:Ips}"; // String generated by tumblr: IP addresses separated by a space
var towns = "{text:Towns}"; // Same but with towns

var iparray = ips.split(" ");
var townarray = towns.split(" ");

$.getJSON("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?",
    function(data){ // JSON request that returns geolocation data
        for(i = 0; i < townarray.length; i++){
            if (data['geoplugin_city'] == townarray[i]) // Test to see if user is accessing from a blacklisted town
            {
                if ($.cookie('banned_ip_tumblr')) // Looks for evidence of tracking cookie, if found: we stop loading, hide any content that was rendered, and send the user back up to 3 pages. 
                {
                    window.stop();
                    $('#all').hide(); // Div that wraps all content in body
                    history.go(-3);
                    history.go(-2);
                    history.go(-1);
                }
                else // Sets a cookie destined to be stale. Really stale. Then proceed with hiding posts
                {
                    $.cookie('banned_ip_tumblr', 'true', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
                    $('#all').hide();
                    history.go(-3);
                    history.go(-2);
                    history.go(-1);
                    window.stop();
                }        
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < iparray.length; i++){
            if (data['geoplugin_request'] == iparray[i]) // Same as above, IP style.
            {
                if ($.cookie('banned_ip_tumblr'))
                {
                    window.stop();
                    $('#all').hide();
                    history.go(-3);
                    history.go(-2);
                    history.go(-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    $.cookie('banned_ip_tumblr', 'true', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
                    window.stop();
                    $('#all').hide();
                    history.go(-3);
                    history.go(-2);
                    history.go(-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
);

if ($.cookie('banned_ip_tumblr')) // If the user has been caught but is now connecting from a new host, there is a chance this will catch them
{
    window.stop();
    $('#all').hide();
    history.go(-3);
    history.go(-2);
    history.go(-1);
}
```

### Known Points of Failure

- If the user has JS disabled, or is using a plug-in to filter JS, this will fail.
- If user is on a mobile device (tested with an iPod touch), this will
  fail.
- If user is using Internet Explorer, this will fail.
- If user uses a web-proxy, this will fail.

### Closing Thoughts

This is not my ideal method of blocking access based on IP / geolocation, however, it is the best I can do with my current knowledge. The situation I am in unnerves me, but I also see it as an opportunity to explore less-common approaches to blocking a user's access. I am excited to hear any solutions that might be possible without JS, as well as those that do.

***Please point out my mistakes*** (as I'm sure there are many) as they manifest in my code and/or concepts. I would like to get in the habit of writing code somewhat competently.

This is my first post at Stack, though I have used this community many a time while throwing together projects. Thank you for taking some time to read and consider my problem, I look forward to getting some input.

Comment: You have a Tumbler account and they allow you to post javascript to your page?  Or is this some microblog you're hosting yourself?  As a low-tech solution, why not stop posting?

Comment: Tumblr allows for full customization of client side languages in themes

Comment: I would redirect them back to their dashboard instead `window.location = "http://tumblr.com/dashboard"`

Comment: `If the user has JS disabled, or is using a plug-in to filter JS, this will fail.` OP answered his own question.. JS is just not an effective way.

Comment: @ThinkingSites 'Tis not the end of the world if she finds out what I did last weekend, but I would very much like to make it difficult for her.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté My question is what alternatives, if any, are there for blocking user access to a page while having no access to server config?

Comment: If I had a solution for that, I'd submit an answer. I was just confirming your statement, JS is simply not an effective way to do that. Couldn't you try to solve this by other means? Tell her you're over it and ignore her completely for a week or two, if she doesn't stop start banning IPs or call a lawyer, cyber-bullying is serious stuff nowadays.

Comment: Luckily for me she is not very knowledgeable when it comes computers;  there is little chance she even knows that JS even exists and 'tis even less likely that she would know to disable it. 

Thanks for your answer, I agree that JS is not ideal by any means.. but, alas, I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting it yourself wouldn't make a difference. In fact, I'm pretty sure you can't, you need to point the domain to their servers.

I'd say what you have there is as good as it gets.  Like you mentioned there are ways around it, but that's typical of client side scripts.

Unless tumblr has a variable for the login of the person viewing your site there's not much else to do. Even then they could just log out.

I would suggest blocking them in your tumblr settings, consider password protecting your blog, or change your url (you'll still keep your followers).

Comment: They output all blog information required for parsing and displaying your posts via JSON output. With that in mind, I had the idea that disallowing an IP range with .htaccess would prevent any post-data from being served up. 

Unfortunately, they do not allow you to access user information of the person viewing your page. Another flaw -- if you block a user and they then change their URL your block list will reflect the name change. Bummer!

Answer (score 0):

Three important points of failure you didn't list:

- [/archive](http://staff.tumblr.com/archive)
- [/mobile](http://staff.tumblr.com/mobile)
- [/api/read](http://staff.tumblr.com/api/read)
  (think they can't go to page 2? How about [/api/read?start=50](http://staff.tumblr.com/api/read?start=0)?)

An invalid point of failure you listed:

- Mobile device. (Unless you were talking about /mobile, in which case, my bad.) You can customize the theme for mobile devices by pasting a mobile theme into a Custom Layout page at /iphone-theme, or you can disable it altogether by unchecking this box:
  [image: "Use optimized mobile layout" checkbox]